# Disproving existence statements

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to get some practice on disproving existence statements and I was really stuck on this one:

"There exists an example of three distinct positive integers different from $a,2a,3a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ having the property that each divides the sum of the other two."

I have tried working with the negation for all distinct positive integers different from $a,2a,3a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ where it each does not divide the sum of the other two, and thought about it using the contrapositive, except that I am not quite sure how to start it.

In fact I was rather stumped on expressing it in generalized terms. Would someone mind helping me out with this ? I think this is quite a good example and was quite difficult for me so I would really like to know the best way to approach such a problem.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question of expressing it, let $a,b,c$ be distinct positive integers.  WLOG assume $a<b<c$.  Suppose that $a\mid b+c, b\mid a+c$ and $c\mid a+b$.  We wish to prove that these hypotheses imply $b=2a$ and $c=3a$ in order to disprove the existence statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One should not worry too much about logic (negation, contrapositives), and instead think about the concrete problem, that is, just think about *numbers*.  What can we discover about numbers such the sum of any two is divisible by the third?

If $x,y,z$ are positive integers, with $x\lt y\lt z$, then it looks "hardest" for $z$ to divide $x+y$. Since $x+y\lt 2z$, the only way we can have divisibility is if $x+y=z$. Nice simplification!

Now we want $y$ to divide $x+z$, so we want $y$ to divide $2x+y$. That can only happen if $y$ divides $2x$. But since $x\lt y$, that forces $2x=y$, and we are finished.

Comment: Wow that was very nice, thank you for the help !

Comment: @PutsandCalls: You are welcome. There are other approaches, but this one is fairly natural once you start fooling around with numbers. In particular, one notices that $x+y$ can't be "big." And then everything falls into place.  I am of course trying to convey a point of view, that a great deal of mathematics is, fundamentally, about concrete properties of concrete objects. To get to grip with these, often one has to erect layers of abstraction, but these abstractions, when one is really working with them, begin to feel pretty concrete.